# Why nuget package installation failed due to not responding of irrelevant package source

Tags: .net-core, nuget-package, nuget-server, azure-artifacts

I was playing with dotnet cli to create f# project. I ran the following command to install NewtonSoft.Json NuGet Package.

```
$>dotnet add src/Library/Library.fsproj package Newtonsoft.Json
```

the output is

```
  Writing C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp440E.tmp
info : Adding PackageReference for package 'Newtonsoft.Json' into project 'src/Library/Library.fsproj'.
info : Restoring packages for c:\Learning\Projects\FSNetCore\FSNetCore\src\Library\Library.fsproj...
info :   GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/newtonsoft.json/index.json
info :   OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/newtonsoft.json/index.json 288ms
error: Unable to load the service index for source https://MyEmployer.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/NuGetServerName/nuget/v3/index.json.
error:   Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).
```

I am wondering why this operation has failed due to 401 response from a irrelevant package source which is a private azure artifacts pointed by [user-level scoped](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/configuring-nuget-behavior) Nuget.Config file.

```
$>dotnet nuget --version
NuGet Command Line
5.2.0.3
```

Package can be installed successfully to projecy by specifying Source and version explicitly

```
$> dotnet add src/Library/Library.fsproj package Newtonsoft.Json --source https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/newtonsoft.json/index.json --version 12.0.2
  Writing C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp8A3B.tmp
info : Adding PackageReference for package 'Newtonsoft.Json' into project 'src/Library/Library.fsproj'.
info : Restoring packages for c:\Learning\Projects\FSNetCore\FSNetCore\src\Library\Library.fsproj...
info : Package 'Newtonsoft.Json' is compatible with all the specified frameworks in project 'src/Library/Library.fsproj'.
info : PackageReference for package 'Newtonsoft.Json' version '12.0.2' added to file 'c:\Learning\Projects\FSNetCore\FSNetCore\src\Library\Library.fsproj'.
info : Committing restore...
info : Writing assets file to disk. Path: c:\Learning\Projects\FSNetCore\FSNetCore\src\Library\obj\project.assets.json
log  : Restore completed in 193.98 ms for c:\Learning\Projects\FSNetCore\FSNetCore\src\Library\Library.fsproj.
```

Why dotnet cli tried to load the service index  from irrelevant package source  ?

Comment: We're experiencing issues with `dotnet restore` with the NuGet CLI 5.2.0.3 as well...

Comment: @Tubs use --ignore-failed-sources option